# Using "faire en sorte que" and "par hasard" in the same sentence

Tags: expressions

> À bientôt. Un jour, je **ferai** peut-être **en sorte qu**'on se rencontre vraiment ***par hasard***.

The phrase "faire en sorte que" conveys the idea that you **intentionally** see to it that something **definitely** happens, correct? The use of "par hasard", on the other hand, indicates that their next encounter is purely ***coincidetal*** – something that happens ***by chance***.

Making sure that a ***chance*** encounter will **definitely** happen? These two ideas do not seem to mix. Is this apparent contradiction meant to be ironic?

Comment: Where did you get this sentence from? I can give ou a piece of answer, but it can be off-topic without some context.

Comment: I don't know if it's ironic, but it's definitely a poetic usage, you understood well the passage, it's supposed to contrast these two different meanings. That's how most of poetry (in the large sense) gimmicks work.

Comment: To @Charly: This is an excerpt of a journal entry, casully written. Their first chance meeting was ***fixed***, so to speak. Contrary to that... This is where the sentence comes in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cette contradiction est un procédé rhétorique appelé [antilogie](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilogie_(rh%C3%A9torique)), la plupart du temps utilisé pour produire un effet comique ou poétique.

---

Such a contraction is a rhetoric formula called [antilogy](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilogie_(rh%C3%A9torique)), usually used to create a comic or poetic effect.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about everything so yes, I suppose it's ironic. Maybe it means 'One day I'll take the decision to never see you again so if we meet in the future, it will be by chance'.